# SSO with openiddict

Tags: single-sign-on, openiddict

When a user logs in from site https://www.siteA.com,
an authentication cookie is recorded.

I want to read this authentication cookie from site https://www.siteB.com using User.Identity.Name.

How should I configure  Program.cs(ASP.NET CORE 6.0) of  Site https://www.siteA.com and Site https://www.siteB.com ?

```
      using AuthorizationServer.Models;
      using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
      using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

      var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

      builder.Services.AddDbContext<DbContext>(options =>
        {
          options.UseInMemoryDatabase(nameof(DbContext));
          options.UseOpenIddict();
        });

       builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()

           .AddCore(options =>
             {
               options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
              .UseDbContext<DbContext>();
             })

           .AddServer(options =>
             {
              options
                 .AllowClientCredentialsFlow();

              options
                .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token");

              options
               .AddEphemeralEncryptionKey()
               .AddEphemeralSigningKey();

              options.RegisterScopes("api");

              options
               .UseAspNetCore()
               .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough();
         });

        builder.Services.AddHostedService<TestData>();
        builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

       builder.Services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
          .AddCookie(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, options =>
                 {
                  options.LoginPath = "/account/login";
                 });

        var app = builder.Build();

        if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
        {
          app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseAuthentication();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
           {
             endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
           });


        app.Run();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use ASP.Net Core Data Protection Keys configuring in your client Applications (i.e SiteA and SiteB).

Have a look at this.
https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core/issues/1109

and this
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/configuration/overview?view=aspnetcore-3.1

hope this helps